# Ruby Rock, Paper, Scissors - Switch statements/loops

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to complete a Ruby Rock, Paper, Scissors challenge but my switch statements and loops don't work together. The first paragraph of my code either repeats or goes blank.

The instructions are as follows:

Write a program that lets two players play Rock, Paper, Scissors. The program should:

- Ask player 1 for their move.  They can input `rock`, `paper` or
  `scissors`.
- Ask player 2 for their move.  They can input `rock`, `paper` or
  `scissors`.
- Calculates who has won.  `rock` beats `scissors`, `paper` beats
  `rock`, `scissors` beat `paper`.
- If player 1 has won, `puts`es `Player 1 wins`.
- If player 2 has won, `puts`es `Player 2 wins`.
- If the game is a draw, `puts`es `It's a draw`.
- Note: You can assume that players will input one of the three
  possible moves described above.
- Note: When you run the automated tests, the tests will simulate
  the user input.  You shouldn't need to enter any input manually.
  If the tests hang when you run them, it probably means your code
  doesn't work correctly, yet.
- Note: You can assume the players will only ever input `rock`,
  `paper` or `scissors`.

I've tried removing the loop section and seeing if the switch statement works by itself, but it doesn't.

```
loop do
  puts "Player 1, you can type rock, paper or scissors."
  player_1_input = gets
  puts "Player 2, you can type rock, paper or scissors."
  player_2_input = gets

case
  when player_1_input == player_2_input
    puts "It's a draw"
    break
  when player_1_input.include?("rock") && player_2_input.include?("scissors")
  when player_1_input.include?("paper") && player_2_input.include?("rock")
  when player_1_input.include?("scissors") && player_2_input.include?("paper")
    puts "Player 1 wins!"
    break
  when player_2_input.include?("rock") && player_1_input.include?("scissors")
  when player_2_input.include?("paper") && player_1_input.include?("rock")
  when player_2_input.include?("scissors") && player_1_input.include?("paper")
    puts "Player 2 wins!"
    break
end
```

I expect the first section not to repeat and for the switch statement to work but it doesn't.

Comment: Where is your `loop` end?

Comment: When I add end to the end of the loop end paragraph, it throws an error. It also doesn't change the fact that the code repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with corrections:

```rb
loop do
  puts "Player 1, you can type rock, paper or scissors."
  player_1_input = gets
  puts "Player 2, you can type rock, paper or scissors."
  player_2_input = gets

case
  when player_1_input == player_2_input
    puts "It's a draw"
    break
  when player_1_input.include?("rock") && player_2_input.include?("scissors") ||
  player_1_input.include?("paper") && player_2_input.include?("rock") ||
  player_1_input.include?("scissors") && player_2_input.include?("paper")
    puts "Player 1 wins!"
    break
  when player_2_input.include?("rock") && player_1_input.include?("scissors") ||
  player_2_input.include?("paper") && player_1_input.include?("rock") ||
  player_2_input.include?("scissors") && player_1_input.include?("paper")
    puts "Player 2 wins!"
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Your outside loop structure is fine except for the missing `end` statement, but you might consider reorganizing it as follows, with `<player 1 wins>` being pseudo-code:

```
PROMPT = "Player %d, please type 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors'."

winner = loop do
  puts PROMPT % 1
  player_1_choice = gets.chomp # don't forget to chomp the newline!
  puts PROMPT % 2
  player_2_choice = gets.chomp
  case
  when player_1_choice == player_2_choice
    puts "Try again"
  when <player 1 wins>
    break 1
  else # player 2 wins
    break 2
  end
end
puts "Player #{winner} wins!"
```

We now need to flesh out `<player 1 wins>`. A convenient way to determine if either player wins is to create the hash

```
WINNERS = { "rock"=>"scissors", "paper"=>"rock", "scissors"=>"paper" }
```

Then player 1 wins if

```
WINNERS[player_1_choice] == player_2_choice
```

We therefore may write the following.

```
PROMPT = "Player %d, please type 'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors'."
WINNERS = { "rock"=>"scissors", "paper"=>"rock", "scissors"=>"paper" }

winner = loop do
  puts PROMPT % 1
  player_1_choice = gets.chomp
  puts PROMPT % 2
  player_2_choice = gets.chomp
  case
  when player_1_choice == player_2_choice
    puts "Try again"
  when WINNERS[player_1_choice] == player_2_choice
    break 1
  else
    break 2
  end
end
puts "Player #{winner} wins!"
```

The `case` statement could alternatively be written as follows (the choice being stylistic only):

```
  case
  when WINNERS[player_1_choice] == player_2_choice
    break 1
  when WINNERS[player_2_choice] == player_1_choice
    break 2
  else
    puts "Try again"
  end
```

Note that this does not run properly in IRB.

Answer (score -1):

Each `when` is a separate statement so in your code this part:

```
when player_1_input.include?("rock") && player_2_input.include?("scissors")
when player_1_input.include?("paper") && player_2_input.include?("rock")
when player_1_input.include?("scissors") && player_2_input.include?("paper")
    puts "Player 1 wins!"
    break
```

essentially translates to:

```
when player_1_input.include?("rock") && player_2_input.include?("scissors") then do nothing
when player_1_input.include?("paper") && player_2_input.include?("rock") then do nothing
when player_1_input.include?("scissors") && player_2_input.include?("paper") then puts "Player 1 wins!"; break
```

In order to have multiple "or" conditions in `case` statement you connect them with  commas like this:

```
when player_1_input.include?("rock") && player_2_input.include?("scissors"),
player_1_input.include?("paper") && player_2_input.include?("rock"),
player_1_input.include?("scissors") && player_2_input.include?("paper")
    puts "Player 1 wins!"
    break
```

then your program should work fine

Comment: when I add commas, I get the error (syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end)

Comment: can you paste the 2 lines between which you put the comma? Maybe you forgot to remove `when` from the 2nd line? I'm running my last snippet and it works fine

Comment: You forgot to add ```end``` after case,  @629060311. Your code should have 2 ends at the end